# Complex integral on a circumference

Tags: complex-integration

I have to integrate the function
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{1+z^2} e^{-2\pi i z \xi}$$
on the upper part of the circumference with center $0$ and radius $R$ in the complex plane. $\xi$ is a real number.
I tried to use polar coordinates but it doesn't help. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

For this integral, you might consider using the so-called ML inequality, which states that if $ |f(z)| \leq M$ and the length of the contour $\gamma$ is less than $L$, then
$$ \left|\int_\gamma f(z) dz\right| \leq ML.$$

Back to the question, can you try to compute the bound of $f$ on the semi-circle on the upper plane? Try to substitute $z = Re^{i\theta}$ directly and simplify the exponent.

Comment: $|f(z)| \leq 1 $ and the length of $\gamma \leq \pi R$.

Comment: You might want to use a 'tighter' bound, $ |f(z)| \leq 1$ is not that useful.
[Hint: you may just leave the fraction as it would be, cause the $z^2 = R^2e^{2i\theta}$ in the denominator is useful in eliminating the $R$]

Comment: The upper bound $M$ should not depend on $\theta$, right?

Comment: Yeah. You should eliminate the dependence of upper bound on any variables except $\theta$.

Comment: So $|f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{1+R^2}$.

Comment: And $\frac{\pi R}{1+R^2}$ tends to $0$ as $R$ tends to infinity. Thus the integral is $0$. Right?

Comment: I don't think that $e^{-2 \pi i \xi z}$ is always bounded...